# Read data from txt file, store it, use it for analyzing, write it to the txt file

Tags: python-3.x

The task is to read from given txt file the data add the numbers in there to the list[], so that every number in a row will be a element/object in this list. After reading the file created list will be sent to the main().
this list with the objects will be parameters for the def Analyze part in where at the same time
will be found min, max, average and sum.
[image: txt file]

```
def lueTiedosto(data):
    Tiedosto = open("L07T4D1.txt", 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
    Rivi = Tiedosto.readline()
    while (len(Rivi) > 0):
        data.append(int(Rivi))
        Rivi = Tiedosto.readline()
    for element in data:
        print(element)
    print(f"Tiedosto L07T4D1.txt luettu.")
    Tiedosto.close()
    return element
```

The fixed code which works:

```
def lueTiedosto(data):
    Lue = input("Luettavan tiedoston nimi on ''.\n")
    print(f"Anna uusi nimi, enter säilyttää nykyisen: ", end='')
    Tiedosto = open(Lue, 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
    Rivi = Tiedosto.readline()
    while (len(Rivi) > 0):
        data.append(int(Rivi))
        Rivi = Tiedosto.readline()
    print(f"Tiedosto '{Lue}' luettu.")
    Tiedosto.close()
    return data
```

Comment: While it is difficult to diagnose exactly what is wrong with out a sample of your input data file, I do have three observations:  (1) Unless you call the function  ```lueTiedosto(data)``` with a list as the argument, you won't get a valid response, (2) Unless the text file contains a single integer per line, the line ```data.append(int(Rivi))``` will throw an error.  (3) The ```return element``` line will return None, since element is only valid in the previous enumerate sequence.

Comment: Anna valintasi: 2
10000
12345
Tiedosto L07T4D1.txt luettu. This is the print preview if i ask to read file

Comment: But when i choose analyse the only thing i get is empty list [] But there should be those two numbers 10000 and 12345 from those analyzing should be made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an assumption that your input file is similar to the following:

```
10000
12345 
10008
12000
```

I would do the following:

```
filepath = r".......\L07T4D1.txt"  # Path to file being loaded

def readData(filepath: str) -> list[int]:
    # Returns a list of integers from file
    rslt = []
    with open (filepath, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readline().strip()
        while data:
            data = data.split(' ')
            rslt.append(int(data[0]))
            data = f.readline().strip()
    return rslt   

def analyze(data: list[int]) -> None:
    # prints results of data analysis
    print(f'Max Value = {max(data)}')
    print(f'Min Value = {min(data)}')
    print(f'Sum Value = {sum(data)}')
    print(f'Avg Value = {sum(data)/len(data)}')
```

Running `analyze(readData(filepath))`  Yields:

```
Max Value = 12345
Min Value = 10000
Sum Value = 44353
Avg Value = 11088.25
```

Comment: Ty, but it still don't  work. We started Python 2 mnths ago and we need "build up" the code in certain way, and i think that's why it just don't work :(

Comment: The test file consist only of two numbers: 10000 in first row and 12345 in second one. But it will be tested with the file were there is numerous of numbers, each in one row.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the txt file format that is representative of what you are trying to do.  Also, specify if you want the max, min, avg and sum by all valuers in file or by row!  Can't provide an answer without adequate definition of problem

Comment: Given that the numbers of interest are each in a separate row, see updates to answer